# AWS S3 bucket doesn't understand VueJS route

Tags: vue.js, amazon-s3, routes

I have a VueJS website with 2 pages, a welcome form and a feedback form.
The welcome form is accessible from the root URL {myS3Bucket}.com/
The feedback form should be accessible form the URL {myS3Bucket}.com/feedback

This is my index.ts:

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: () => import('@/layouts/default/Default.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Home',
        component: () => import('@/views/Home.vue'),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/feedback',
    component: () => import('@/layouts/default/Default.vue'),
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Feedback',
        component: () => import('@/views/Feedback.vue'),
      }
    ],
  },
]
```

This works fine locally when running `npm run preview`
When I upload the website on my S3 bucket, the root works fine, but the `/feedback` returns `403 Forbidden`.

The S3 bucket is configured as static website hosting, with public access allowed.

How do I make my S3 bucket understand this URL and serve me the right vue?

PS:
Adding a policy allowing all just changes the error to `404 Not found`

PS2: I found a workaround by changing the error document to `index.html`, but I'm sure there is a cleaner solution.